# Laravel validation requiredIf with array index

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, validation, laravel-validation

I need to apply a `required` rule to a array field in my form request when the another array field, in the same index, has a certain value. Example:

```php
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
       'data' => 'array',
       'data.*.is_admin' => 'required|boolean',
       'data.*.area' => [
           'nullable',
           Rule::requiredIf($condition),
           // other rules...
       ]
    ]
}
```

When evaluating the first item in the array, if `data.0.is_admin = 1`, I'll add `required` to `data.0.area`. The problem is that I'm unable to access the current index inside the `requiredIf` method.

Using closures I was able to access the current index, but I can't override the `nullable` rule unless I add a `required` one and I need to be able to pass `null` to `area`. I can't use `sometimes` because I need to ignore the other rules when `area = null`.

Right now I'm looping through `$request->data` and adding the rules conditionally for each index. I wonder if there is a way I can achieve this using Laravel's array sintax.

Thank you

Comment: Yeah, for conditions like that, you generally need to use a loop for assign `data.$i.is_admin` and `data.$i.area` rules based on each other. `.*.` rules are for when each index is isolated in its validation. So create a `$rules` array, use a loop to add rules to it, then `return $rules;`

Comment: This works for me:
'data.*.area' => 'required_if:data.*.is_admin,1'